Optimal function to scan numpy matrix
I have a binary 2D numpy array that represents transactions and items. For item I (represented as columns), I want to calculate the total number of transactions (represented as rows) that purchased this item, all items that were purchased alongside item i, and all transactions associated with those items. This is done to calculate support, confidence, and lift between items. My current implementation uses a nested loop but it takes too long for a large dataset. Is there a way to scan a matrix optimally when I need to scan the entirety of it each time?
Here is my code with an example array.
import numpy as np
results = []
data = np.array([[0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1]])
N = data.shape[0] #total transactions
for i in range(4): # for each item i
    #transactions% where item i was purchased
    mask_i = data[:,i] == 1
    support_i = data[mask_i].shape[0]/N
    for j in range(4): # check all items j
        #transactions where both i and j are purchased
        mask_j = data[:,j] == 1 
        support_j = data[mask_j].shape[0]/N #transactions% where j is purchased
        mask_c = np.logical_and(mask_i,mask_j) # mask for where both i and j were purchased
        confidence = (data[mask_c].shape[0]/N) / support_i
        lift = confidence/support_j
        results.append([i,j,confidence,lift]) #store combination

The results list will show each identified combination of item with other items.
[[0, 0, 1.0, 2.0], [0, 1, 1.0, 1.3333333333333333], [0, 2, 0.5, 2.0], [0, 3, 1.0, 1.0], [1, 0, 0.6666666666666666, 1.3333333333333333], [1, 1, 1.0, 1.3333333333333333], [1, 2, 0.3333333333333333, 1.3333333333333333], [1, 3, 1.0, 1.0], [2, 0, 1.0, 2.0], [2, 1, 1.0, 1.3333333333333333], [2, 2, 1.0, 4.0], [2, 3, 1.0, 1.0], [3, 0, 0.5, 1.0], [3, 1, 0.75, 1.0], [3, 2, 0.25, 1.0], [3, 3, 1.0, 1.0]]


I get TypeError: array() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Where are the results? are you looking for data.T @ data??

Updated post to fix code and include an expected output.
